# How to change the background of a whiteboard using the Circuit SDK?

Tags: javascript, circuit-sdk

I would like to start a whiteboard using the Circuit SDK (Javascript) and then set the background as an image (load it from a local file or upload one). Is it possible? Does anybody know how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `setWhiteboardBackground(callId, file)` method what sets the background of the whiteboard, where acceptable parameters are

- **callId** String - a Call ID of the call;
- **file** File - a File object for background image.

See more details [here](https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_setWhiteboardBackground).

Answer (score 0):

There is a whiteboarding jsbin on circuit.github.io which show how to set the background image. 
https://output.jsbin. com/jeguyah